# making a constant heading - css issue

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, ajax

I have an AJAX application which has used CSS divs to create panels on the screen, which are loaded separately and in succession, depending on what was loaded before it. The bottom "panel" is a table showing a list or records from a database. At the top of the database is the name of the table, and I would like a way to have it be always above the list of records. I am unsure of how to do this, if it is with Javascript, or PHP, or css and html.

edit: I tried wrapping the table header in a div and setting the css for this purpose, but the table header does not seem to be in its own header and does not stay on screen separate from the records.

```
.tableheader {
    position: absolute;
}
```

and

```
$table = 'AUCTIONS';

$rows = getRowsByArticleSearch($query, $table);

echo '<div id="tableheader" class="tableheader">';

echo "<h1>{$query} Auctions</h1>" . "\n"; 
echo "</div>";
```

Have I missed something fundamental here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean to be able to scroll the table without moving the header?

I think your easiest option is the CSS [`overflow` property](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_overflow.asp).

```
<style type="text/css">
  div#dblist {
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 400px;
  }
</style>

<!-- ... -->

<div>Database Title</div>
<div id="dblist">
  <table>
    <!-- ... -->
  </table>
</div>
```

---

@Joshxtothe4: It sounds like you've got scrolling set to the wrong element:

```
<div> <!-- sounds like you have it set here -->
  <div><h1>Query Archive</h1></div>
  <div> <!-- and want it set here -->
    <table>
      <!-- ... -->
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

You shouldn't need absolute positioning for this.

Comment: That is basically what I did, as the table layer was already set to scroll, so I just put the header in a separate layer, but it made no difference..

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I thought I had the correct logic, but have now pasted my entire css file and html, because it is still not working and I am unsure why.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the table name to be inside the panel with the table?  If so, I think it should be pretty straightforward, but maybe I am missing something.

If you want the table name to be positioned outside the panel it comes from, perhaps you could use the CSS property `position: absolute` (along with a `top` and `left` property) to put it at the top of the page.

Alternatively, you may want to use javascript to re-parent the div.  For example, if you create an empty div at the top of the page, where you want the title to go, and give it an id `titleParent` and put the title in a div with id `parent`, the following javascript snippet should move the title div from the bottom panel to the top div:

```
var title = document.getElementById('title');
document.getElementById('titleParent').appendChild(title);
```

Just put that snippet in a `<script>` block after the bottom panel.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use tbody (table body) to contain your data, and set overflow:scroll on that element to get the effect you are looking for.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Page Title</title>

        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        table {

            margin:0;
            padding:0px;
        }

        tbody {
                height:80px;
                overflow-x:hidden;
                overflow-y:scroll;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }
        table td, table th{ padding:2px;}

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr><th>Header</th><th>Header</th><th>Header</th><th>Header</th></tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```